# Vaadin change Textfield Label color

Tags: java, css, vaadin, vaadin14

I am looking for a easy way to change the Label color of the Vaadin TextField Component.
It changes automatically to blue when the Textfield is on focus, but I need to change it to another color.
First I tried it to change it in the css file like this:

```
color: <anycolor>;
```

But this has only changed the input text color. Is there a way to change only the color of the label? I am using Vaadin 14.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you check the CSS applied to the `<label>` tag in the browser DevTools (F12 or Ctrl+Shift+C), you'll see that it's

```css
:host([focused]:not([readonly])) [part="label"] {
    color: var(--lumo-primary-text-color);
}
```

There's 2 options how to customize that:

1. **Change the variable.**
   You can write `--lumo-primary-text-color: green;` to set the value of that variable in your **global CSS**. Multiple options:

   1. on that one specific textField `textField.getStyle().set("--lumo-primary-text-color", "green")`, or
   2. Apply it to fields with a class, `textField.addClassName("green-text")`

      ```css
      green-text {
          --lumo-primary-text-color: green;
      }
      ```

      , or
   3. Apply it to ALL text fields:

      ```css
      vaadin-text-field {
          --lumo-primary-text-color: green;
      }
      ```
2. **Overload the CSS with a more specific rule.** You'll need to add this to `vaadin-text-field`'s **shadow DOM** with

   ```java
   @CssImport(value = "./styles/path/yout-vaadin-text-field.css", 
   themeFor = "vaadin-text-field")
   ```

   ```css
   :host(.green-text[focused]:not([readonly])) [part="label"] {
        color: green;
   }
   ```

Comment: Can you add a mention of what is “DevTools”?

Comment: F12 in your browser. Then use inspect HTML.